# How would I extract data from forecasts at certain times from an XML API response in PHP and display them as HTML tables?

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm a little lost with how I would go about doing this but I need to get a forecast for the next 5 days of a city using OpenWeather's forecast api, but they do it in 3 hour intervals and I only need the forecasts for midday and midnight on each day. How would I go about filtering through each forecast to check if the time is from "12:00:00" or from "00:00:00". I understand you'd use a foreach loop here, but the bit I'm confused about is testing the condition when the format is like this.

`<time from="2021-03-27T15:00:00" to="2021-03-27T18:00:00">`

Is there a way I can get the from value and then split it from the T character and then just conditionally check if it matches what I need, and then if it matches I echo out a new table? I've included the full pastebin of the XML response if anyone wanted to check it. Many thanks!

https://pastebin.com/AT1WSfUe

Answer (score 0):

Using the [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and that date format is one of the automatically understood formats for a date and time

```
$from = "2021-03-27T15:00:00";

$dt = new DateTime($from);
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
27/03/2021
15:00:00
```

Comment: So if I was to store those two formats that you echo'd in variables could I use them in conditionals within a foreach loop to filter out the dates and times that I need?

Comment: Yes you can do that